# Wait for pop up window to close in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there any command to wait for the popup to close.nActually my project is like on home page popup will appear and after choosing city pop gets close. Then I am able to click on sign in button. But when i run the script, before closing the pop up my next  command which is  click on sign in  button are executing. So test script getting fail. When I used sleep (10000),then my script is working fine. But every time i don't want to use sleep,

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us42R.png)

Please help me with your answers

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would wait for the popup to be hidden :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000); // 5 seconds timeout
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("popup locator")));
```

Comment: Hi Florent, please advise whether "popup locator" is text of the element or class or any other property?

Answer (score 1):

One way to loop over and over rather than a fixed wait:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Accept the expected alert 
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

    //Wait dynamically to disappear 
    int i=0;
    while(i<15)
    {
        try{
            driver.switchTo().alert();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch(NoAlertPresentException a){
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        i++;
    }
```